# unmet dependencies in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, apt

I tried today to install a dvb-card on my Ubuntu 12.04 `(Linux blauhai-linux 3.2.0-25-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 23 20:30:51 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
)`. The installation failed with an error. After that, i tried to install python (it was already installed but i got this error):

```
linux:~$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-glade2:i386 : Depends: python:i386 (< 2.5) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python-support:i386 (>= 0.3.4) but it is not installable
                      Depends: python:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libglade2-0:i386 (>= 1:2.5.1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: python-gtk2:i386 (= 2.8.6-8) but it is not going to be installed
 python-numeric:i386 : Depends: python:i386 (< 2.5) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: python:i386 (>= 2.3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: python-central:i386 (>= 0.5.7) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

well, i can read and tried the proposed command, but then i get this:

```
linux:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libopenal1:i386 libsdl-ttf2.0-0:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libgconf-2-4:i386 libsm-dev libatk1.0-0:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libstdc++5:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386
  libxcomposite1:i386 libice-dev libgail18:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libao-common libv4l-0:i386 liblcms1:i386 libqt4-qt3support:i386 libroken18-heimdal:i386
  libunistring0:i386 libcupsimage2:i386 libgphoto2-port0:i386 libidn11:i386 libnss3:i386 libcaca0:i386 gtk2-engines:i386 libgudev-1.0-0:i386
  libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libpthread-stubs0 libcairo-gobject2:i386 libavc1394-0:i386 libjpeg8:i386 libotr2 libaio1:i386 libsane:i386 odbcinst1debian2
  odbcinst1debian2:i386 libqt4-test:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-designer:i386 libsdl-mixer1.2:i386 libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libcap2:i386
  libproxy1:i386 ibus-gtk:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libtdb1:i386 libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libspeex1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libgomp1:i386 libcapi20-3:i386
  libibus-1.0-0:i386 libcairo2:i386 libgnutls26:i386 libopenal-data odbcinst libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libcanberra0:i386 libtasn1-3:i386 libfreetype6:i386
  x11proto-kb-dev gtk2-engines-murrine:i386 libwavpack1:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 libv4lconvert0:i386 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386
  libc6-i386 lib32gcc1 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 librsvg2-common:i386 libdatrie1:i386 xtrans-dev libavahi-common-data:i386 libiec61883-0:i386 lib32asound2
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libsdl-image1.2:i386 libp11-kit0:i386 x11proto-input-dev libwind0-heimdal:i386 libpixman-1-0:i386 libsdl1.2debian:i386 libxaw7:i386
  libgdbm3:i386 libcups2:i386 libcurl3:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libesd0:i386 libmikmod2:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 libxft2:i386 libxt-dev
  libcroco3:i386 libpulse-mainloop-glib0:i386 libice6:i386 libaa1:i386 libieee1284-3:i386 libgcrypt11:i386 libthai0:i386 libao4:i386 libkeyutils1:i386
  libxmu6:i386 libcanberra-gtk0:i386 libvorbisfile3:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 esound-common libxpm4:i386 libqt4-svg:i386 libusb-0.1-4:i386 libgail-common:i386
  libxrender1:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libraw1394-11:i386 libnspr4:i386 libshout3:i386 libdv4:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libxau-dev libqt4-xml:i386
  gstreamer0.10-x:i386 libgettextpo0:i386 libxss1:i386 libgd2-xpm:i386 libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libtiff4:i386 libsdl-net1.2:i386 libjasper1:i386
  libgnome-keyring0:i386 libxtst6:i386 gtk2-engines-pixbuf:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libtag1c2a:i386 librsvg2-2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libssl0.9.8:i386
  libmpg123-0:i386 libmad0:i386 libsasl2-2:i386 xorg-sgml-doctools libgsoap1 gtk2-engines-oxygen:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 xaw3dg:i386 libpango1.0-0:i386
  libsm6:i386 libx11-dev libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libpulsedsp:i386 lib32stdc++6 libx11-doc libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libxcb-render0:i386 libodbc1:i386
  libexif12:i386 libqt4-scripttools:i386 librtmp0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libxi6:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libxcb1-dev libxp6:i386 libaudio2:i386
  libxcursor1:i386 libxcb-shm0:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libxrandr2:i386 x11proto-core-dev libsqlite3-0:i386
  libmng1:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386 libxdmcp-dev libpthread-stubs0-dev libltdl7:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libssl1.0.0:i386 glib-networking:i386
  libgpg-error0:i386 libsoup2.4-1:i386 libgphoto2-2:i386 libtag1-vanilla:i386 libaudiofile1:i386 libglade2-0:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common libglade2-0:i386 libpython3.2 openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib python3 python3-minimal python3-uno python3.2 python3.2-minimal
Suggested packages:
  icedtea-plugin sun-java6-fonts fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho ttf-telugu-fonts ttf-oriya-fonts ttf-kannada-fonts ttf-bengali-fonts python3-doc
  python3-tk python3.2-doc binfmt-support
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  activity-log-manager-control-center aisleriot alacarte apparmor apport apport-gtk apt-xapian-index aptdaemon apturl apturl-common bluez bluez-alsa
  bluez-alsa:i386 bluez-gstreamer checkbox checkbox-qt command-not-found compiz compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf deja-dup
  duplicity eog evolution-data-server firefox firefox-globalmenu firefox-gnome-support foomatic-db-compressed-ppds gconf-editor gconf2 gdb gedit
  gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 gksu gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-bluetooth gnome-contacts
  gnome-control-center gnome-media gnome-menus gnome-orca gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-session-fallback gnome-shell gnome-sudoku gnome-terminal
  gnome-terminal-data gnome-themes-standard gnome-tweak-tool gnome-user-share gstreamer0.10-gconf gwibber gwibber-service gwibber-service-facebook
  gwibber-service-identica gwibber-service-twitter hplip hplip-data ia32-libs ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 ibus ibus-pinyin ibus-table indicator-datetime
  indicator-power jockey-common jockey-gtk landscape-client-ui-install language-selector-common language-selector-gnome launchpad-integration
  libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk-module:i386 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcompizconfig0 libfolks-eds25 libgksu2-0 libgnome-media-profiles-3.0-0
  libgnome2-0 libgnome2-common libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libgweather-3-0 libgweather-common libgwibber-gtk2 libgwibber2 libmetacity-private0
  libmutter0 libpeas-1.0-0 libpurple-bin libpython2.7 libreoffice-gnome librhythmbox-core5 libsyncdaemon-1.0-1 libtotem0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 light-themes
  lsb-release metacity metacity-common mutter-common nautilus-dropbox nautilus-share network-manager-gnome nvidia-common nvidia-settings
  nvidia-settings-updates onboard oneconf openjdk-7-jdk openjdk-7-jre openprinting-ppds pidgin pidgin-libnotify pidgin-otr printer-driver-foo2zjs
  printer-driver-ptouch printer-driver-pxljr printer-driver-sag-gdi printer-driver-splix python python-appindicator python-apport python-apt python-apt-common
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-aptdaemon.pkcompat python-brlapi python-cairo python-central python-chardet python-configglue
  python-crypto python-cups python-cupshelpers python-dateutil python-dbus python-debian python-debtagshw python-defer python-dirspec python-egenix-mxdatetime
  python-egenix-mxtools python-gconf python-gdbm python-gi python-gi-cairo python-glade2:i386 python-gmenu python-gnomekeyring python-gnupginterface
  python-gobject python-gobject-2 python-gpgme python-gst0.10 python-gtk2 python-httplib2 python-ibus python-imaging python-keyring python-launchpadlib
  python-lazr.restfulclient python-lazr.uri python-libproxy python-libxml2 python-louis python-mako python-markupsafe python-minimal python-notify
  python-numeric:i386 python-oauth python-openssl python-packagekit python-pam python-pexpect python-piston-mini-client python-pkg-resources
  python-problem-report python-protobuf python-pyatspi2 python-pycurl python-pyinotify python-renderpm python-reportlab python-reportlab-accel python-serial
  python-simplejson python-smbc python-software-properties python-speechd python-twisted-bin python-twisted-core python-twisted-names python-twisted-web
  python-ubuntu-sso-client python-ubuntuone-client python-ubuntuone-control-panel python-ubuntuone-storageprotocol python-uno python-virtkey python-wadllib
  python-xapian python-xdg python-xkit python-zeitgeist python-zope.interface python2.7 python2.7-minimal rhythmbox rhythmbox-mozilla
  rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune rhythmbox-plugin-zeitgeist rhythmbox-plugins rhythmbox-ubuntuone screen-resolution-extra
  sessioninstaller skype software-center software-center-aptdaemon-plugins software-properties-common software-properties-gtk system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome system-config-printer-udev texlive-extra-utils totem totem-mozilla totem-plugins ubuntu-artwork ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-minimal
  ubuntu-sso-client ubuntu-sso-client-gtk ubuntu-standard ubuntu-system-service ubuntuone-client ubuntuone-client-gnome ubuntuone-control-panel
  ubuntuone-couch ubuntuone-installer ufw unattended-upgrades unity unity-2d unity-common unity-lens-applications unity-lens-video unity-scope-musicstores
  unity-scope-video-remote update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk virtualbox
  virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt xdiagnose xul-ext-ubufox zeitgeist zeitgeist-core zeitgeist-datahub
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  default-jre default-jre-headless icedtea-6-jre-cacao icedtea-6-jre-jamvm icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common libglade2-0:i386 libpython3.2 openjdk-6-jre
  openjdk-6-jre-headless openjdk-6-jre-lib python3 python3-minimal python3-uno python3.2 python3.2-minimal
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  python-minimal python2.7-minimal (due to python-minimal)
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 273 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 39.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 324 MB disk space will be freed.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
 ?]
```

Thats not good, is it?! Should i run this command or should i run another command to fix this problem?
Would be great if somebody can help me. :)
Thanks in advance.

best regards

Comment: No, that's not good. http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies has some standard advice on this kind of problem. You might also use `sudo aptitude` to get another view of what the problem is and your alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried all solution of this link. At last, i tried `apt-get install -f` but this broke my whole system. So i had to install it from scratch :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I remembered that I had switched my python version in the **/usr/bin** folder from **2.7** to **3.2**. Switching back resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Most probable cause of problem

The probable causes of this kind of problem are:

- You installed an essential system package like `python` from a latest PPA, and then removed the PPA, since many packages are dependent on `python` package and since, `apt-get` always try to install highest versioned package and packages in official repository is not the highest one, it will not downgrade, but give you error
- If you removed/disable a repository which contains the necessary *(dependency)* package, `apt-get` also give you error in this case.

### Solution:

- If you added a PPA, and remove that later, You should add that PPA again, do `sudo apt-get update` and try again. It should work. *Unless that PPA is not working now, In that case, You are very unlucky now)*
- If you disable any repository, *most probably the updates repository*, you should enable that repository and do `sudo apt-get update` and try again with your command. It should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for your input! My system was before i tried to install the dvb-stuff up-to-date. In the error of the installation was some xxx.py stuff, then i tried to install python. But the result of the `apt-get install python` command was the error you can read in my post. I tried `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade`, and some other proposed solutions in [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies). Anyway, i reinstalled ubuntu and now it works again :)

Comment: @lee.O, This means you do not need the answer and actually the problem is gone now. am i correct?

Comment: It didn't work for me :/, but thanks. Yes, the actually problem is now gone.