# Network Manager missing after update: no connectivity

Tags: network-manager, chroot, wicd, via

After an update and restart, I found that the network icon on the top is missing and so, I cannot connect to LAN, wifi, USB modem, nothing. Now, I am booting from a Live USB, then `chrooted` to my original Ubuntu partition. I tried to install `wicd` by

```
root@ubuntu:/# apt-get install wicd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wicd : Depends: wicd-daemon (= 1.7.2.3-1ubuntu0.1) but 1.7.2.3-1 is to be installed
wicd-daemon : Depends: python-wicd (= 1.7.2.3-1) but 1.7.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried

```
apt-get -f install
```

but still the problem remains.

How to fix this ? What am I doing wrong? I want to install wicd on my original Ubuntu partition. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstalling the `network-manager`. To do it use the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager-gnome
```

To solve the problem of not able to install `wicd`, first install the dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-daemon
sudo apt-get install python-wicd
```

Now, try installing `wicd`.

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager : Depends: libnl-route-3-200 but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: network-manager-gnome but it is not going to be installed or
                               network-manager-kde but it is not going to be installed or
                               plasma-widget-networkmanagement but it is not going to be installed
 wicd-daemon : Depends: python-wicd (= 1.7.2.3-1) but 1.7.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Every time i enter a command like sudo apt-get install package, I get an error like this..
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wicd-daemon : Depends: python-wicd (= 1.7.2.3-1) but 1.7.2.3-1ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Maybe these will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/155514/unmet-dependencies-in-ubuntu-12-04 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies.